# How to save varchar field for query performance in mysql innodb

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization, innodb

I made the following sample table.

```
CREATE TABLE `User` (
  `userId` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userKey` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userId`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`userKey`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

I want a more quick query speed for the `userKey` field.

```
SELECT * FROM `User` WHERE userKey='KEY123'
```

In order to do that, what else should I consider besides the index?

- For example, when saving the `userKey`, would using a value such as a DATE(sortable value) as prefix be more beneficial to the search speed?
- Or, if I save the `userKey` as the hash value, will it improve?
- If not all, is it **enough to use the index** for the above query?

Comment: If you are searching by `userKey` alone, the current unique key (which is also indexed) should be enough.  If you have _other_ queries, then we would need to see what they are in order to comment.

Comment: Let's see the query/queries that are "too slow" because of fetching from this table.

Comment: You haven't shown the query you want to optimize, so folks can only guess at a strategy.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared `userKey` as `UNIQUE`, so MySQL will automatically create an index for you. That should generally be enough, given that you are searching by "exact match" or by "starting with" type of queries.

If you consider storing hash values, you would only be able to perform "exact match" queries. However, for short strings that may turn out to be not really worth it. Also, with hashes, you need to consider the risk of a collision. If you use a smaller hash value (say 4 bytes) that risk increases. Those are just some guidelines. It's not possible to provide a definitive solution without delving into more details of your case.

Answer (score 0):

One way to speed the table is to get rid of it.

Building a mapping from an under 20 char string to a 4-byte INT does not save much space.  Getting rid of the lookup saves a little time.

If you need the to do the 'right thing' had have one copy of each string to avoid redundancy, then what you have is probably the best possible.

If there are more columns, then there may a slight improvement.
But first, answer this:  Do you do the lookup by UserKey more of often than by UserId?

I give a resounding NO to a Hash.  (Such might be necessary if the strings were too big to index.)

A BTree is very efficient as doing a "point query".  (`FROM User WHERE UserId = 123` or `FROM User WHERE UserKey = 'xyz'`).  Adding a date or hash would only make it slower.